# Django admin - Is there a way to have all object types in one form field?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

The title might not be very clear. I'll try to explain be giving examples.

In my project, I have 6 different "content" apps. And we have several plugins we can put in pages (django-cms) having the possibility to have a link to any of thoses 6 apps.

But now, the only way I have for doing so, is to add a Foreign key for each apps, in each plugin.

Is there a better way ? Or is there a form field with the ability to link multiple different apps ?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you need is [generic relations in forms and admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations-in-forms-and-admin) - does this help?

Comment: I'm probably too new in Django to know exactly what to do with all this. But I Form Field that we could set which class to display (all in the same dropdown list) would be amazing !

Comment: it's hard to be sure without knowing more about the details of your project but yes, you probably want to use generic relations. I recommend a prototype implementation to see if it can solve your problems.